# Google+ circle membership check by API

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-plus

Is it possible to use the Google+ API to check if a user is a member of another users particular circle?

Example use case:

User Joe adds User Bill to "Joes Friends" Google+ Circle

User Joe is also a user on my website "videos-from-my-weekend.com"

Joe Picks a particular video from my site, then grants access to that video to anyone in his "Joes Friends" Google+ Circle.

User Bill logs in to my website, and is able to watch Joe's videos.

Nefarious Steve tries to watch Bill's videos, but fails the Google+ api check since he's not a member of the "Joes Friends" Google+ Circle.

I hope I explained that clearly enough.

This is really a code independant question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to check a particular circle, then no you can't do that.

If you're trying to check that the viewing user exists in any circle, then the following conditions must be met:

- Users must have authorized your app to request their friends list by requesting the auth scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`, which is included by using [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) or you can just do a straight OAuth 2.0 flow with it.
- When the user authorizes your app, they have a choice of whether to allow your app to know about all, some, or none of their circles. The a flat list of people from any circles they allow your app to see would be available with [`people.list`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list).
- After they authorize your app, you make requests and [get both of their friend's lists](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_a_collection_of_people) and store those in your DB for checking nefarious Steve against later.

Comment: Thanks, I was digging around the API but coudln't find the exact workflow.

So are you saying that I could check if Nefarious Steve exists in any of Joe's circles, but I can't check to see if he has membership in a particular circle?  

In other words I can't ensure Nefarious Steve is in the "People I share things with" Circle, but I can get a boolean response back saying "Yes, Steve happens to be in one of Joe's circles"  even if that circle happens to be the "People I would never share anything with" circle ?

Comment: It is more complex than that. All you can verify is that they are in some circle that Joe is willing to share with you. You won't know if he's in a circle that was not shared with you, nor in which circle (of those shared with you) he is in. So if he doesn't share the "Evil Enemies" circle with you when he permits your app access, you won't know if Steve is in it or not.